# How to check if an element is actually holding some data

Tags: c#, selenium

*My problem is I am trying to test if the element is present, but I would like to be able to check if that element is actually holding some data or it is just empty.*

The element I am searching for look something like this :

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">

            </ul>
```

*Obviously this unordered list is empty. How can I check if it is holding some data inside or not ? Any suggestions?*

Comment: Are you programming Selenium via C#?

Comment: @g.pickardou Yes I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

Supposing you get your UL nodes via FindElement, you can always search within an IWebElement further with its FindElements method.

```
var ulElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("your xpath"));
foreach (var ulElement in ulElements)
{
    var contentElements = ulElement.FindElements(By.CssSelector("your css"));
    if (...) {}
}
```

... or ...
b)

Please note you can search by XPath or by CssSelector. If you choose to search primarily by CssSelector, then you can form a CSS selector which is UL which has at least LI. But this is not about Selenium neither C#, so I recommend it to ask specifically this (UL which has LI) as a separate question and tag it with CSS however this selector is infamous about it not exists in current CSS spec but who knows what the future brings

Answer (score 0):

You can check in following way:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\ul[@class='list-unstyled']")).getText();
```

getText() will try to retrieve data from element. Then you can check whether its blank or not.

Comment: If the UL contains LIs with no text then UL's text will be empty

Comment: If it does not contain any text, it will return blank string and not empty. You need to get text and check whether its blank or not.

Comment: empty == blank, and btw in C# empty is the term. Otherwise not that was the point, instead I meant examining text is not enough